# How can I remove Unknown Invitees listed when Adding invitees to event?

Tags: iphone

On my iPhone 7plus i created an event and selected INVITEES and two names I don't recognized appeared; how do I remove them (and how did they get there) The names do not appear on my contact list.

Comment: Screenshot please

Comment: from an email maybe?